Enumeration of Permutations of $0–9$ Satisfying Closure Under Doubling
A number is defined as a SMART number if its digits form a permutation of the digits $$\{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9\}$$. For example:

$1027348659$ is a SMART number.
$0217348659$ is a SMART number.
$123456789$ is also considered SMART, as it can be interpreted as $0123456789$. We do not require the leading digit to be non-zero(unlike the definition of pandigital number)
$123539678$ is not SMART because the digit '$4$' is missing, and '$3$' appears twice.
$412839678$ is not SMART because the digit '$5$' is missing, and '$8$' appears twice.

The problem I wish to pose is the following:
Determine the number of SMART numbers such that their double (i.e., twice the number) is also a SMART number.
I have been working on this problem for several days but have not yet arrived at a solution. I would appreciate any help. Thank You.
My Attempt
Let's say, ABCDEFGHIJ is smart. I denote by $X$ one among $A-J$, and $'X$ and $X'$ denotes the digit on left and right respectively(if they exists). For example, if $X=D$, then $'X=C$ and $X'=E$.
It we multiply by $2$, then the corresponding place in $2(ABCDEFGHIJ)$ contains $2X + [X'/5]$ in its decimal expansion. Morever if $X$ and $Y$ differ by $5$, and if $X',Y' \leq 4$ then the digits under $X$ and $Y$ would be same which would imply that $2(ABCDEFGHIJ)$ is not smart. If this particular condition is satisfied, then we have that the number $2(ABCDEFGHIJ)$ is indeed smart. This hold because, the digit $Z \in \{0, 1, 2 \dots 9\}$ will come under either $[\frac{Z}{2}]$ or $[\frac{Z}{2}] + 5$. We also want $A \leq 4$
Hence I conclude that $ABCDEFGHIJ$ is a smart number, whose double is also a smart number if and only if

$A \leq 4$, and
If $X$ and $Y$ differ by $5$, then either $Y'
    \leq 4 < X'$ or $X' \leq 4 < Y'$

But I am not sure how to count such numbers.
This problem can be geometrically translated to tracing a path on a $2 x 5$ grid, with the condition that, the path starts from first column, and at any stage the line segment starting from the boxes in same row must land in boxes in different columns. However I have not been able to make much progress here.
I used the following mathematica code, and the answer turns out to be $92160$

(* Generate all permutations of digits 0 to 9 *) permutations =
Permutations[Range[0, 9]];
(* Convert a list of digits to a number *) toNumber[digits_] :=
FromDigits[digits];
(* Define the upper limit ) limit = 510^9;
(* Function to check if a number and its double are SMART )
isDoubleSMART[num_] := Module[{doubleNum},    doubleNum = 2 * num;
( Check if the double is within the limit and is SMART *)
If[doubleNum > limit, False,
Sort[IntegerDigits[doubleNum]] === Range[0, 9]] ];
(* Filter permutations within the range and check their doubles *)
countSMART = Count[    permutations,     perm_ /; (1 <= toNumber[perm]
<= limit && isDoubleSMART[toNumber[perm]]) ];
Print["Count of SMART numbers where double is also SMART: ",
countSMART];


Why not start with a smaller problem, like ${0,1,2,3}$ or such?  At least get a sense of the computation goes.

For instance, what is the least $N$ for which there is a smart number in base $N$?  Well, not counting $2\times 01=10$ which doesn't seem very interesting.

I thought about it, for example, if we consider smart numbers for say ${0,1,2,3}$ then doubling will introduce $4,6$ and $8$ which does not help. If you are talking about reconsidering the base, then that is a good idea.

Yes, I think you need to lower the base to make an interesting question.  My $2\times 01=10$, trivial example, is base $2$ of course.  I don't believe any base $3$ or base $4$ examples exist, but I just did it hastily and might have got it wrong.

Interesting Question? I think the above question is interesting as well.

Yes, but the smaller base question is a lot easier.  Always good to solve easier versions of a problem as they arise.

For the base 4 question, I found 6 numbers Smart numbers whose doubles are also smart numbers: 0213, 0321, 0312, 1230, 1203, 1302.

cool, I think the cases where the base is even or odd will also matter. right?

Yes. The base must be even else the sum of the digits is a barrier. You need the sum of all the digits to be $0 \pmod {b-1}$, where $b$ is the base.

As far as I see, sometimes if $X'$ does not exist then we deal with $X'$ as with the zero, for instance, in the conditions 1 and 2.

X' would not exists for the digit in units place, for that there is no restriction. For example, If we consider the 10 digit number to be $"ABCDEFGHIJ"$,Then $X'$ would not exists for $X=J$.

@Nic You missed 0123 and 1032.

As far as I see, the code truncates the SMART numbers $n$ to consider because the limit $5\cdot 10^9$, corresponding to condition 1, is imposed on $2n$ instead of $n$. Indeed, Anders Kaseorg's
answer
shows that the required number is $230400>92160$.

You’ve seen that we have these constraints on valid numbers (SMART numbers whose double is SMART):
(a) each digit is used exactly once;
(b) the first digit is less than $5$;
(c) for $0 ≤ i < 5$, exactly one of the digits after $i, i + 5$ is at least $5$.
From each valid number, we can extract this tuple of data:

The ordering among the digits $0, 1, 2, 3, 4$.
The ordering among the digits $5, 6, 7, 8, 9$.
Whether the digit after the earlier of $0, 5$ is at least $5$.
Whether the digit after the earlier of $1, 6$ is at least $5$.
Whether the digit after the earlier of $2, 7$ is at least $5$.
Whether the digit after the earlier of $3, 8$ is at least $5$.
Whether the digit after the earlier of $4, 9$ is at least $5$.

For example, from $1027348659$ we extract $(10234, 78659, N, N, Y, N, Y)$.
One of the yes/no answers is forced: namely, if $i$ is the last digit among $5, 6, 7, 8, 9$, then the digit after the earlier of $i - 5, i$ must be at least $5$ (because if there’s a digit after the later of $i - 5, i$, it can only be less than $5$).
Given any such tuple, we can reconstruct exactly one valid number from left to right using (a), (b), and (c): at each step there will be exactly one choice for the next digit.
Therefore, there are $5!^2 ⋅ 2^{5 - 1} = 230400$ valid numbers, and more generally, there are $k!^2 ⋅ 2^{k - 1}$ valid numbers in base $2k$.

This is nice. Thanks. I have been banging my head over this problem for a while
